# Regular Expression begining of string with special characters

Tags: regex

Using this for an example string

```
+$43073$7
```

and need the 5 number sequence from it I'm using the Regex expression

```
@"\$+(?<lot>\d{5})"
```

which is matching up any +$ in the string. I tried

```
@"^\$+(?<lot>\d{5})"
```

as the +$ are always at the beginning of the string.  What will work?

Comment: Which language and RE syntax are you using? PHP? PERL? something else?

Comment: Looks like you've got the `+` and `$` in the wrong order. Try `^\+\$`… and see if that does the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use anchor `^`, you need to include the `+` symbol at the first and don't forget to escape it because `+` is a special meta character in regex which repeats the previous token one or more times.

```
@"^\+\$(?<lot>\d{5})"
```

And without the anchor, it would be like

```
@"\$(?<lot>\d{5})"
```

And get the 5 digit number you want from group index 1.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aZ6zX0/2)

Answer (score 0):

I would match what you *want*:

```
\d+
```

or if you only want digits after "special" characters at the start of input:

```
^\W+(\d+)
```

grabbing group 1